# C/C++ graph library query node by atributes

Tags: c++, graph, attributes, structure, igraph

Is there a C++ graph library in which you can query vertices by attribute value ?

Like the python vers. of igraph:

```
seqIDs = myGraph.vs.select(attribute1, attribute2)
```

Comment: Can you, please, explain why do you think this should be part of the library? Are you expecting index (i.e. being faster than O(num_vertices)) or something like that?

Comment: Since it was part of the python vers. of igraph I was hoping for this feature in the C version. 

I am thinking of implementing a separate Vector that is ordered by attribute1 (index) which stores Structs with the id of the node and the 2nd attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at Boost Graph Library ([BGL](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html)) already ? It allows to parametrize vertices so you'll be able to use standard algorithms to look through them.

Comment: It seems a little complicated. I have aprox 100 nodes with two properties (index and pronunciation) and make around 100 000 calls to a method findNode() I doubt I can write a function with a low time complexity

Comment: Boost code is peer reviewed, so things like performance, accuracy, scalability and complexity are being covered. I agree though that if you look for your features + easy coding this might be overkill.